# binding form using formGroup in angular component

Tags: angular-formbuilder

I'm facing below error while binding the form

```
cart.component.html
<h3>Cart</h3>

<p>
  <a routerLink="/shipping">Shipping Prices</a>
</p>

<div class="cart-item" *ngFor="let item of items">
  <span>{{ item.name }} </span>
  <span>{{ item.price | currency }}</span>
</div>

<form [formGroup]="checkoutForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    <div>
      <label for="name">
        Name
      </label>
      <input id="name" type="text" formControlName="name">
    </div>
  
    <div>
      <label for="address">
        Address
      </label>
      <input id="address" type="text" formControlName="address">
    </div>
  
    <button class="button" type="submit">Purchase</button>
  
  </form>

cart.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

import { CartService } from '../cart.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart',
  templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart.component.css']
})
export class CartComponent {
  items = this.cartService.getItems();
  checkoutForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: '',
    address: ''
  });
  constructor(
    private cartService: CartService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    ) {}

  onSubmit(): void {
    // Process checkout data here
    this.items = this.cartService.clearCart();
    console.warn('Your order has been submitted', this.checkoutForm.value);
    this.checkoutForm.reset();
  }
}
```

error :
Failed to compile.

src/app/cart/cart.component.html:12:7 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

12 <form [formGroup]="checkoutForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/cart/cart.component.ts:8:16
8   templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component CartComponent.

Answer (score 0):

just add into your app.module.ts

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

and under @NgModule

```
 @NgModule({
   imports: [
     FormsModule, 
     ReactiveFormsModule,
```